# Linux corrupts customized TCP option

Tags: docker, tcp, checksum

I am facing a peculiar problem with TCP options in k8s/Cilium/Kind.

I have added a customized TCP option to the SYN packets being sent out from an endpoint using Cilium's `bpf_lxc` program (an eBPF program attached to the ingress tc hook of veth).

When the packets pass through the `tc` egress eBPF program on `eth0` (the host NIC), the TCP option appears to be correct. However, when I capture the packet using Wireshark before it is actually sent out, I notice that the TCP option has been corrupted.

If the TCP option is 16 bytes long, the 13th and 14th bytes are corrupted. If the TCP option is 20 bytes long, it is the 17th and 18th bytes that get corrupted.

The modified 2 bytes seem to be randomly altered.

At the moment, I am unsure of what could be causing this issue. Any input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
TCPOption(Unknown(45): 0x0af400c50a600065c6300050000004a40000)
TCPOption(Unknown(45): 0x0af400c50a600065c6300050000000000000)
```